# Keep multiple objects with the same key in DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to create ASP.NET MVC web application using Entity Framework Code First.
I have two simple models

```
 public class Assignment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Initiator")]
        public int InititatorId { get; set; }
        public virtual User Initiator { get; set; }

        public virtual List<User> Debtors { get; set; }
        public virtual List<User> Responsibles { get; set; }

        public Assignment()
        {
            Debtors = new List<User>();
            Responsibles = new List<User>();
        }
    }

 public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
    }
```

and my DbContext looks like

```
 public class AssignmentContext : DbContext
    {

        public DbSet<Assignment> Assignments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Assignment>()
                .HasRequired(r => r.Initiator)
                .WithMany()
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false); 

            modelBuilder.Entity<Assignment>()
                .HasMany(m => m.Responsibles)
                .WithMany()
                .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.MapLeftKey("AssignmentId");
                    m.MapRightKey("UserId(Responsible)");
                    m.ToTable("AssignmentResponsibles");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Assignment>()
                .HasMany(m => m.Debtors)
                .WithMany()
                .Map(m =>
                    {
                        m.MapLeftKey("AssignmentId");
                        m.MapRightKey("UserId(Debtor)");
                        m.ToTable("AssignmentDebtors");
                    });
        }
```

**Is there a way to keep the same User instance in the Lists Debtors and Responsibles?**

Because I'm getting the error when I'm trying to save changes.

```
An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.
```

I need to do this because it is required by the application logic.

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

Here on HttpPost the error appears (The same error in Console app sample):

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Text,CreationDate,InititatorId,Debtors,Responsibles")] Assignment assignment)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                assignment.Debtors.RemoveAll(r => r.Name == "Roman");
                db.Entry(assignment).State = EntityState.Modified; // HERE!
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.InititatorId = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "Name", assignment.InititatorId);
            return View(assignment);
        }
```

Debtors and Responsbiles elements from the view are passed by hidden input.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, are you sure that's all the code you have?

Comment: @YuliamChandra yes you are right, when we create DB the error doesn't appears. But when we try to change something (delete one entry in Debtor list) we get the error in code `db.Entry(assignment).State = EntityState.Modified;`

Comment: @YuliamChandra I do not know it or not allowed, but I'll take on myself to post link to archive which contains two versions of my project (**console and asp.net-mvc**) [**from googledrive**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4a4mpg7rb4AUnpUMGJvVzlxM00/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: please post your code here when trying to change something, the related code only..

Comment: @YuliamChandra Thanks for your reply. Code is added in the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just get the data first instead of directly attach it to the dbcontext, the same assignment with the same id might have been attached locally within the same context.

instead of these

```
assignment.Debtors.RemoveAll(r => r.Name == "Roman");
db.Entry(assignment).State = EntityState.Modified; // HERE!
db.SaveChanges();
```

try these

```
var assignmentDb = db.Assignments.FirstOrDefault(asg => asg.Id == assignment.Id);
assignmentDb.Debtors.RemoveAll(r => r.Name == "Roman");
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you! You are right! But in addition to this situation I must add `db.Entry(assignmentDb).CurrentValues.SetValues(assignment);` to apply changes received by HttpPost.

Comment: But why the `Assignment` instance can be attached to the context without any changes (just as it received from the user with changes on his side) and cannot be attached when I delete something?

Comment: @user172805, yup, you need to apply the changes from `ui entity` to `db entity`, but I prefer to apply the changes manually db.X = ui.X, because the `ui entity` might be harmful

Comment: your `dbcontext` variable `db` is stored as class field variable, the `dbcontext` could have load the entity when you attach it the first time, I prefer to always create the dbcontext per Action and dispose it right away to prevent unexpected behavior like this

Comment: Hmm, when I debug the app the `db.Dispose();` method is called with all request.

Comment: IMO you should use `using(var db = new YourDbContext()) { ... }` on every action..